# How to write a value in span tag?

Tags: jquery

I need with jquery to update value in span

```
<p id="my_balance"><span class="pr-1">EUR</span>&nbsp;999,999.99</p>
```

If I make it with code

```
  $("#my_balance").html(formatted_balance);
```

san is not updated. If I make it :

```
  $("#my_balance > span").html(formatted_balance);
```

Value is written AFTER  tag and I have 2 values  old and current. Which is valid way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your value is *not* inside a span...  put it inside one and give it a class and it'll be easy `$("#my_value > span.value")`.  Having said that, it depends on *exactly* what `formatted_balance` contains.

Comment: share also your `formatted_balance` value. does it contain currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write like this

```
let myBalance = $("#my_balance");
let span = myBalance.find("span");

myBalance.html('New Text');
myBalance.prepend(span);
```

Replace New Text with the value you need

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. Try to make the simplest example, so that you understand how you target the element in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my_balance").find("span.pr-1").text("YEN"); // pass your Currency type
  //You can also use html Just uncomment the below line to test.
  //$("#my_balance").find("span.pr-1").html("<strong>YEN</strong>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="my_balance"><span class="pr-1">EUR</span>&nbsp;999,999.99</p>
```